# Symfony2 Route get parameter only if integer

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I got defined routes in routing.yml file

one route is:

```
Profile_user_profile:
    path:    /profile/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: ProfileBundle:Users:profile }
    methods: [get]
```

and second is:

```
Profile_accept_connection_proposal:
    path:    /profile/acceptProposal
    defaults: { _controller:ProfileBundle:Users:acceptConnectionProposal }
    methods: [put]
```

First route without methods: [get] listen also and [put] request and catch second url before it get to route definition. Is there way to define checking for parameter only if url is numeric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the `requirements` parameter to accept only digits for a determined route like this:

```
Profile_user_profile:
    path:    /profile/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: ProfileBundle:Users:profile }
    methods: [get]
    requirements: <--- ADDED PARAMETER
        id: \d+
```

For more infos read the [Symfony book about Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements). There you can find more advanced example on how to use route parameters.

Answer (score 8):

You can now do this with Annotations in your controller like so:

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/profile/{id}", name="user_profile", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     */
    public function profile($id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

More info on [Symfony's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)
Specifically  [defining routing requirements](https://symfony.com/doc/master/routing/requirements.html)

Comment: For Symfony 6, do that : `#[Route('/profile/{id}', name: 'user_profile', requirements: ['id' => '\d+'])]`